# Django clean method cause is_valid() false

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

here is my **model**:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    available = ProductStockManager()
```

and I have a **form** like this:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    description = forms.Textarea()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'stock']

    def clean_description(self):
         pass

    def clean_price(self):
        pass

    def clean_name(self):
        pass
```

in my form when I use `clean_field()` for each field it makes `is_valid()` False except `clean_description()` what is this for ?

why when I use `clean_price()`, `clean_name()` my `is_valid()` returns False?

and why it doesn't when I use `clean_description()` ?

Comment: Presumably your clean methods are doing something other than `pass`ing in your real implementation? They're supposed to return the new value for the field. If you actually haven't implemented them further then that could be why, as they'll return `None` by default and your fields might not like being nulled.

Comment: The `clean` method should *return* the value cleaned. If you do not want to do extra cleaning, then do *not* add these.

Comment: yes thats right. I didn't return anything for fields that are not suppose to be null so is_valid() returns False and clean_description() worked because description allowed to be null. that helped thanks. @Kemp